# .htaccess [OR] condition not met causes unexpected RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

We have  a very large .htaccess file in which we create RewriteRules based on different domain RewriteCond. We use the [OR] flag to make sure both the "www" and domain conditions are met and then Redirect to specific pages.

**Example :**

```
# DOMAIN 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^en/contact$ https://domain1.com/en/contact.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/nouvelles$ https://domain1.com/fr/articles.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/career$ https://domain1.com/en/career.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/contact$ https://domain1.com/fr/contact.html [L,R=301]

# DOMAIN 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^fr/maison-payante$ https://domain2.com/fr/articles.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/cash-damming$ https://domain2.com/en/articles.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/nos-proprietes$ https://domain2.com/fr/nos-proprietes.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/40km-program$ https://domain2.com/en/articles.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/mes-proprietes$ https://domain2.com/fr/nos-proprietes.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/our-properties$ https://domain2.com/en/our-properties.html [L,R=301]
```

**The problem**

Visiting http://domain1.com/en/40km-program will redirect to https://domain2.com/en/articles.html.

The following rule is applied even though the RewriteCond is not met :

```
RewriteRule ^en/40km-program$ https://domain2.com/en/articles.html [L,R=301]
```

The .htaccess file syntax seems good (checked in two different syntax checker tools).

How could this happen ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there cannot be multiple RewriteCond cannot be following by multiple RewriteRule :

The RewriteCond directive defines a rule condition. One or more RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive. The following rule is then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its pattern, and if these conditions are met.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html

**This sums it all :** 
https://serverfault.com/a/214521/59126